# Every time my app launches (whether from cold launch or background) I want to have it do something, how do I accomplish this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

I want to check every time the app launches whether or not there's a URL in the clipboard, and if so, do something with it. Which method fires that I can override whenever the app launches, whether from a cold launch (it was killed in the background for instance) or if I just press the home button, copy a URL and jump back in.

Is it one of these?

```
 - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
 - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
 - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive
 - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
```

Confused.

Comment: Add NSLog statements or breakpoints to the methods you mentioned and try in the simulator, which event fires under which circumstances.  Or, check the apple docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As @rmaddy says, the correct method to use once the app launched is `applicationWillEnterForeground:` from your app delegate.
This method will be called when the user jump backs in, but NOT in other circumstances you don't need to respond to (such as the user receiving a text message and dismissing it).

However, from my testing, `applicationWillEnterForeground:` is *not* called when an app is launched from cold; you should catch that in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

So, basically, your app delegate should include code like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [self checkForURL];
    ...
}


- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {

       [self checkForURL];
       ...
}

- (void)checkForURL{
    //code for checking for URL goes here
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Or call `applicationWillEnterForeground` from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Comment: It seems like applicationWillEnterForeground is sometimes called when the app shuts down itself and is relaunched again from cold. Confirm this if anyone had this happen too.

Answer (score 0):

`- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive` is called when the app is launched or becomes active from the background.

This doc explains everything pretty well: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

Comment: This is not the proper method. It is called far more than just app start or returning from the background.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. Still, it might be a good method for what he wants to do?

Answer (score 0):

With reference to the [UIApplicationDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) Protocol, the handling of app launches can be handled in 2 methods:

- `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`
- `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

And the handling of app launches from background can be handled with the help of method:
 `applicationDidBecomeActive:`

Based on the above call, you can handle your application.

Comment: ApplicationDidBecomeActive is not the correct method. You want applicationWillEnterForeground.

Answer (score 0):

In your app delegate add it to the methods that the other answers have suggested (applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:).  In your root view controller register for the following notification.  This will always be called when your application launches once it has already started running.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(bringingItBack)      name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
```

This will cover both the instances when the app launches and when you are just bringing it back from the background.